# Can you create a coroutine BufferedBroadcastChannel that will store the values received even when not consumed in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I have a library that produces values from reading data from different sources and offers them to a flow from which the user of the library can collect

to do so I use this code

```
private val dataChannel = BroadcastChannel<Reading>(10) 

val dataFlow get() = dataChannel.asFlow()

//this may be triggered by a 5 different threads
fun newReading(type:String, value:Float, time:Date, level:Int) {
    dataChannel.offer(Reading(type,value,time,Level.fromValue(level))
}
```

the user can do something like this to get the data

```
lastJob?.cancel()
lastJob = launch {
    lib.dataFlow.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default).collect { reading ->
       val result = processReading(reading)
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           Toast.makeText(application.applicationContext, result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
    }
}
```

this works as expected, when the user launches the job my library may keep on sending data and the user of the library will keep on receiving them

however if the user cancels `lastJob` and then after a few seconds launches it again they will loose the data received by my library between those two times

is there away to make `dataChannel` store all the readings received through `offer` in that timespan (up to the buffer level of 10 set in its constructor) and when the `dataFlow` becomes active again to emit those values at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out some of the following options:

1. `BroadcastChannel<String>(Channel.BUFFERED).asFlow()`, this will initialise your channel with the capacity of the `DEFAULT_BUFFER_PROPERTY_NAME`, which is **64** by default, but in can be overridden on JVM.
2. You can create a `Channel(Channel.UNLIMITED)` then `consumeAsFlow()`, but yeah, having an unlimited buffer is generally a bad practice
3. Create a `Channel(Channel.RENDEZVOUS)`, and use `send()` instead of `offer()`. Rendezvous channels are basically channels with 0 capacity and whenever your values are not consumed/collected, it will suspend the `send()` call.

Comment: for case 1, that's what I did, it doesn't store in between values,
for case 2, it does indeed seem like a bad option, I want it to have an inner buffer,
for case 3, I don't want to suspend the send/offer calls, I want for them to keep going,
I went with creating an internal first in first out stack of readings btw, when a new reading is received if the channel is active it will send it there otherwise it will save it to the stack, when the channel becomes active it will pop all stack items and send them, this ofc means that there is no chronological ordering to offered items

Comment: For the 3rd option you don't necessarily have to suspend the whole function, you could just wrap the `send()` in a coroutineScope, that way your functions should run the same way, however emitting on the channel will be blocked, until you have a new subscriber

Comment: when you say emitting it on the channel is blocked, do you mean the function that actually calls `send()` will block at the point of `send()` and not move on? or do you mean that it will keep on going but the data that was sent will be buffered and released when someone re-subscribes to the channel's flow?

Comment: the `send()` itself will be blocked, as it is a suspend function. So I'd say this would act as an emulated buffer or fake buffer only. Since with `RENDEZVOUS` you don't really have a buffer, but with the `send()` combination you send only when someone can accept it, so you won't lose out items. Theoretically is not the same as a buffer, practically I'd say however will cover most of the use-cases